# Import xcode scheme from command line

Tags: ios, xcode

Is any way to import an `xcode scheme` into a `xcode project` or `xcode workspace` from command line?

I want to automatize the archive process with a shell script and I want to verify if the scheme exist in the `xcode project` or `xcode workspace`, if the scheme doesn't exit import it from a `.xcscheme` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually pretty easy to achieve. As you have figured out already, Xcode schemes are just files that reside in the xcodeproj container "file".

If you want to check if a scheme exists you just need to check if the `.xcscheme` file is present in either of the following locations: `<your_project>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/<your_user>.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/`
`<your_project>.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/`

If not you just need to copy it there (preferably to the `xcshareddata/xcschemes/` folder).

The following code should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set to your project and scheme

export PROJECT_FILE="MyProject.xcodeproj"
export SCHEME="abc.xcscheme"

# Generate path to shared schemes folder

export SCHEMES=$PROJECT_FILE/xcshareddata/xcschemes

if [ ! -f $SCHEMES/$SCHEME ]; then

    # Create folder if necessary
    mkdir -p $SCHEMES

    # Copy scheme
    cp $SCHEME $SCHEMES/$SCHEME
fi
```